# Pytorch unexpected behaviour after fork

Tags: python, pytorch, fork

I have an application with PyTorch and Gunicorn.
Firstly, I build models(torch Modules) in the Gunicorn Master Worker, and then Gunicorn forks the process, creates workers and serves requests. All the calculations are done on the `CPU`.

The new feature is parallel computation per request, so I fork the Gunicorn worker processes one more time in order to achieve parallelism on the Gunciorn worker level.
That's how I create new processes (as I read fork method is default one when using `.start()`):

```
class Worker(multiprocessing.get_context('fork').Process):
```

It is used this way:

```
Worker().start()
```

Inside new process I access computation pipeline via global variable.

As I read in documentation after `fork` torch internal state should be kept same if you don't modify it, because of page cache and `fork` nature (and it is).

But. Sometimes in docker environment weird behavior occurs, data in state_dict is incorrect(different with parent process) as a result output vector is incorrect. For example expected vector is `[0.0001, 0.3, 0.1]`, but I get: `[112, 4, 43]`, the difference visible to the naked eye. It happens only in a docker environment and a very rare case that's why I'm having difficulties fixing it. Maybe each 30 start is with this bug. I wasn't able to create a minimal code example with bug repetition.

What I tried:

1. https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/a6736ac8518aff7bb88aa0454ba0de43e49a57b3/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L2465 Calling this method `share_memory()` in parent process (Master worker).
2. `torch.multiprocessing.set_start_method('fork', force=True)` set the start method explicitly.
3. `multiprocessing.set_start_method('fork', force=True)` set the start method explicitly.
4. Increasing shared memory in docker: `--shm-size=4G`
5. `torch.multiprocessing.set_sharing_strategy(new_strategy)` trying both `file_system` and `file_descriptor` strategies (before I increased the allowed number of open FD per process).

What I haven't tried

1. Sending addresses of shared state via Queue to child processes as it is shown here https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/multiprocessing.html in CUDA section. (Because I don't use GPU yet I expect `fork` is enough)
2. Calling share_memory() method in child processes.

`torch.set_num_threads()` - is set to `1` in my App.

I have to use a `fork` for the sake of saving RAM. I do not run out of RAM when this behavior occurs.

Keep in mind that everything was working correctly when I just had the Gunicorn workers, inside Gunicorn they use `os.fork()` method for forking. But I checked that `Process.start()` and `os.fork()` are identical. Memory usage has not been increased that's why I'm sure that processes are forked correctly.

I don't modify/update any data after fork, so it is impossible that I corrupted torch state.

I have read a lot of warnings, like: If you want PyTorch to work properly, just don't fork processes. Unfortunately it is not an option for me.

I use Ubuntu 20 in docker, Python 3.9, torch version is 1.8.1. Pytorch state is loaded from a git lfs via load_state_dict().

Please if you have met this behavior share with me any insights.

Comment: no thoughts on the specific issue, but why are you trying to share state between workers?

Comment: @Karl in order to not copy state, I have 10 gunicorn workers, each of them forked 10 times more, all models(torch modules state and other stuff) consumes 15GB, that's why I fork and share it. If not it will consume 15GB * 10 * 10 RAM instead of just 15GB

Comment: Why not have a single worker with a single model running batch inference? You could parallelize CPU compute at the pytorch level

Comment: It is out of topic but I have a features graph computation, some features are complex dssm features, the computation time for them 100ms or more, but they can be calculated in parallel, that’s why I divide graph to components by weight and compute them in parallel. It is online computations that’s why latency is crucial, if have single worker which consumes 15 RAM and handling only one request simultaneously it will be waste of resources.

Comment: I parallelise on the PyTorch level as well but this bug occurs without PyTorch parallelism that’s why I didn’t mention it

Comment: `single worker ... handling only one request` you're not understanding, I'm taking about a batched inference queue. Also, are you actually saving ram with this approach? My understanding is gunicorn workers have copy on write which would just create copies of the model anyway.

Comment: Batched inference queue will lead to a higher response time in any case, I have batching in offline computations, but it is disabled in online version, bug occurs without batching that’s why I’m skipping this complexity. I will move from gunicorn approach in near future as well, but for now it is given and I have to fix it in current architecture. 
When you fork process data is not copied immediately it will be copied when it is modified in Linux by default. Of course gunicorn will occupy some extra space but it is a trifle compared to 15GB of models state, models are not changing after fork